# Why JQuery code does not work when i click on button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the problem with my JQuery code when I click on the button it does not work, I searched a lot and tried many ways but my problem not solved. I used this code in other files, on there it works correctly but it not work in this file.

**this my table:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                              
       <tbody>
         <?php
          $insideOrders = \App\OutsideModel::where('total_id', '=', $order->order_id)->get();
                                ?>
                    @foreach($insideOrders as $index => $inside)
                         <tr>
                            <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $inside->menu->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $inside->menu->category->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $inside->order_amount }}</td>
                            <td>
                                @if($order->status=='1')
                                   <button id="send_order" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
                                     order_id="{{$order->order_id}}">ارسال<i id="send_icon"></i>
                                   </button>
                                     @else
                                      <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" disabled>ارسال شده</button>

                                     @endif
                                   </td>
                              </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>                
         </table>
```

**This is my js:-**.

```
$('table tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
        var order_id = $(this).attr("order_id");

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{route('sendOrders')}}',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'id': order_id
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    alert('ارسال شد!');
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    alert('ارسال نشد!')
                }

            }, error: function (err) {


            }
        })

    });
```

Comment: What is not working? It didn't trigger click or something else?

Comment: Did you try any debugging ? Have you tried to add a console.log inside the click event ?

Comment: when i click on button it does not work

Comment: @frogeyedman yes I did but nothing happend

Comment: Make sure your table is rendered before you script executes. To test that attach even to the body and specify the second parameter for click to select button inside your table

Comment: How should I do that, I did not get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, I put my table inside a dive like below, I don't know what happens when I put it inside a dive. but it works now.

```
<div id="apended_tb">
     <table class="table table-bordered">
                          
   <tbody>
     <?php
      $insideOrders = \App\OutsideModel::where('total_id', '=', $order->order_id)->get();
                            ?>
                @foreach($insideOrders as $index => $inside)
                     <tr>
                        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $inside->menu->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $inside->menu->category->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $inside->order_amount }}</td>
                        <td>
                            @if($order->status=='1')
                               <button id="send_order" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
                                 order_id="{{$order->order_id}}">ارسال<i id="send_icon"></i>
                               </button>
                                 @else
                                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" disabled>ارسال شده</button>

                                 @endif
                               </td>
                          </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>                
     </table>
</div>
```

**Then:-**

```
 $('#apended_tb table tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {........}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace this

```
$('table tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
```

with following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#send_order', function () {
```

And there is a mistake change order_id with

```
data-order_id
```